# Import third-party javascript libs into react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I created my react app with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). For my app, I need pace-progress, perfect-scrollbar, etc., there are third-party libs.
I tried to import `pace-progress` in `index.js` file as following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import 'pace-progress';
import App from './App/AppContainer.bs';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

And the compiler complains:

> ./node_modules/pace-progress/pace.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'pace' in '/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/pace-progress'

The structure of the **pace-progress** looks as following:

[image]

As you can see, there is nowhere a default `index.js` file.
How can I import the files?

Comment: I suggest you to use this package instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pace-progress.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this by running npm install pace --save

ie. installing pace explicitly into the root of the node_modules folder

Answer (score 0):

You can always load these libraries in your root HTML file, like `index.html` and then reuse it in your app. You should load your app separately and reach the 3rd party libraries from the `window` scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with module definition of pace

```
define(['pace'], function() {
  return Pace;
});
```

(This defines a pace as a dependency, and pace on npm is an unrelated CLI progress bar package that this project doesn't depend on.)

You can read more about this in [this issue on pace repo](https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/issues/328)

Unfortunately, because of this, solutions are not pretty.

One way to get around this is to change webpack config to add this

```
module: {
    rules: [
        { 
            test: require.resolve("pace-progress"), 
            loader: "imports-loader?define=>false"
        }
    ]
}
```

This requires ejecting create react app. I'd advice against that. My suggestion would be to go for a different library to show progress bar.
You could go with [react-progressbar.js](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/react-progressbar.js/), [react-component/progress](https://github.com/react-component/progress) or go with a UI framework if you need a lot more components [UI frameworks for react](https://hackernoon.com/the-coolest-react-ui-frameworks-for-your-new-react-app-ad699fffd651)